# Angular 5 - How to watch data change between sibling components without refreshing page?

Tags: angular

I have two sibling components, the first component has `select` box with different `option` bind to a variable called `selectedValue`. When I change the value of options in the first component, I want the same value is changed in the second component. However, the second component keeps showing undefined value. These two sibling components have `ngOnInit` at the same time.

Here is my code:

component1.ts:

```
selectedValue: any;
tokens: Tokens;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTokens();
    this.sharedService.pair.next(this.selectedValue);
  }

  loadTokens() {
    this.apiService.getTokens()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.tokens = data;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

component1.html:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Choose a pair" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let token of tokens" [value]="token.shortName">
    {{token.name}}
  </mat-option>        
</mat-select>
```

shared.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  pair = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  observable: Observable<any> = this.pair.asObservable();
}
```

component2.ts:

```
pair: any;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.pair = data;
      console.log(this.pair);
    });
  }
```

Comment: ngOnChanges helps you to detect any input change

Comment: hmm, I never used it before, do you know any demo or reference link? Thanks

Comment: https://ngdev.space/angular-2-input-property-changes-detection-3ccbf7e366d2 try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you call `.next` before a value is even set. What you should be doing is:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Choose a pair" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="emit($event)"></mat-select>

emit(selectedValue) {
  this.sharedService.pair.next(selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: It's still undefined in component 2 :(

Answer (score 1):

You should dispatch new `selectedValue` value on each change.
For example
component1.html:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Choose a pair" 
            (ngModelChange)="this.sharedService.pair.next($event);"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let token of tokens" [value]="token.shortName">
    {{token.name}}
  </mat-option>        
</mat-select>
```

Or, instead of observables, create field `pair: string` on service and bind it to `ngModel`.
component1:
`[(ngModel)]="sharedService.pair"`
component2:
`{{sharedService.pair}}`

Comment: Cool, I got what your meant, it should work as you suggested. Thank you.